# Deleting a tableview cell if switch is turned off

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a table view that show lots of cells (I made it with a storyboard), and in other view there is a switch, I want that when this switch is turned off, the cell that it represents disappears from the table view, the view with the switch is connected to the tableview by a tab bar.

How do I do it? I don't have idea!

[image: my storyboard]

Comment: Sorry Gabriel, but could you provide a little more information? Controllers? Some Pseudo or Sample code? It's a little hard to understand how everything you have already fits together.

Answer (score 1):

When the switch is turned off, call `[tableView reloadData]` and in your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` check the switch's property to see whether it is turned off. If turned off, return 0.

Comment: i don't want to hide ALL the cells, just one... But thanks anyway!